# IGrouping in ObservableCollection using data grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question
I Have a collection of object witch i use GroupBy on something like this for instance

```
this.ObservableCollection ValuesGroupped = new ObservableCollection<IEnumerable<IGrouping<byte, Values>>> { Currents.GroupBy(value=> value.Id) };
```

This of course is a View model property, now I am trying (with no luck), to display such a collection, exmaple datagrid xaml:

```
                        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesGroupped}" RowHeaderWidth="10">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="65" Binding="{Binding ValuesGroupped.Key}" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

When I do that on flat model structure it worksfor example :

```
public ObservableCollection<ValuesData> Values = new ObservableCollection(valuesData);
```

It works.

Now is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group data in a `DataGrid`, but not using Linq's `GroupBy`operator.  You need to access your data through a `CollectionViewSource`, which can apply grouping, sorting, and filtering for you:

```xml
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">

  <!-- Create a grouped collection view. -->
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedValues" Source="{Binding Currents}">
      <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Id"/>
      </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </DataGrid.Resources>

  <!-- Bind the grid's ItemsSource to the grouped collection view. -->
  <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource GroupedValues}" />
  </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
</DataGrid>
```

If you run this, you'll see that the `DataGrid` does not separate the groups at all.  By default, grouped data is presented similarly to sorted data.  We can override `GroupStyle` to add headers for each group and to make the groups expandable and collapsible:

```xml
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
              <Expander IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding Name}">
                <Expander.Content>
                  <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander.Content>
              </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
  </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

The results are functional, if not terribly pretty.  I would personally restyle the `Expander` to look similar to Explorer, Outlook, etc.

[image: Screenshot]

You'll may also want to sort by the group key.  In that case, add a `SortDescription` to your `CollectionViewSource`:

```xml
<CollectionViewSource xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
                      x:Key="GroupedValues"
                      Source="{Binding Currents}">
  <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Id" />
  </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
  <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" />
  </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```